# Laravel 5 Hash function runs very slowly on shared host

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently developing a simple API using Laravel for Android devices.
I am trying to authenticate every request so that I know the request is made by a legitimate user. To do so , I require every legitimate request to include parameters user id and key. The android application will get the information needed upon user's successful login and store it in the device.
Every request from the device will contain the user id and key as parameters.

I use middleware to check every request here's the code :

```
class AuthenticatedUser {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $input = $request->only('userID','key');
        $u = User::where(['id' => $input['userID']])->first();
        if($u && Hash::check($input['key'],$u->app_key)){
            Session::flash('user',$u);
            return $next($request);
        }
        else{
            return response(['status' => 'ERROR' , 'message' => 'AUTH_FAILURE', 'payload' => [] ],401);
        }
    }

}
```

Basically, the middleware checks if the a user with the given user id and key exists, and if the user exists, it will store the user in a temporary session. If no such user exists, it will return an error.

My problem is that every request would take 800-1000 ms. After some tinkering I found out that Hash::Check is the cause of the delay. I tried to remove the Hash::Check code and every request would take roughly 300-400ms

Then I tried to deploy this application on two different free VM Workspace services, and the request would take around 350-400ms with the Hash::Check intact. What could possibly cause this ? Why would Hash::Check function takes a very long time on shared host but not on VMs ?

The PHP version used on the shared host is 5.4.41 , and the PHP version of the VM is 5.5.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely to be just a matter of different resources. Even if a VM uses 1/8th of your PC's resources, that's probably double what you will get on a shared host.

You could either lower the work factor to speed up the hashing process (which would also reduces the brute-force resistance). One option you could look into is  [JSON web tokens](http://jwt.io/introduction/).

Comment: Thanks for the reference on JSON web tokens. I finally understand how it works and it helps. I'm still unclear about the VM part though. Is it better to host a project on VM or Shared Host ?

Comment: In a shared hosting environment, multiple users share hardware resources on a single hardware server (also known as the 'Noisy Neighbor' problem). With a VM you are more likely to  get the advertised resources (CPU, RAM etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Newest guidelines on IT security suggest using slower hashing functions, because the user is logging into web site once and this login is maybe a little bit slow but the slower login process hampers brute force attack.

If you are checking credentials in every rest request you should consider using other hash function.